# Printing complex objects attributes Struts2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I'm upgrading Struts2 from `2.3.15.3` to `2.3.29` and I've found a problem when I try to show attributes values of complex objects (attribute is on an object inside other object) in a JSP page.

I'm using `<s:label name="object1.object2.attribute"/>` to show attribute's value and it doesn't appears but, if I create on form view class a method like that:

```
public Long getTestAttribute() {
    return object1.getObject2().getAttribute();
}
```

and reference it on JSP with `<s:label name="testAttribute"/>` it appears on the page.

Also I've tried with `text` and `hidden` tags, but I have the same problem.

Comment: Was it working on 2.3.15.3 ? Is it possible that you're using some special word (maybe reserved in OGNL, not in Java) as attributes name ? Have you double-checked getters and all ? Do you have attributes names which the first word is one-letter only ?

Comment: If I use <s:label name="object1.object2.attribute"/> on 2.3.15.3 that works but on 2.3.29 not. The attributes name don't match with special words  or has attributes names with one letter.

Comment: Very weird. Have you changed only the struts2-core jar or also the other jars (ognl, ecc...) ?

Comment: I've changed freemarker (2.3.19 -> 2.3.25), ognl (3.0.6 -> 3.0.19), tiles-core and tiles-jsp(2.1.2 -> 2.2.2) and struts plugins for spring, tiles and dojo to 2.3.29. I've changed that libraries following the release notes from struts 2.3.15.3 to 2.3.29.

Comment: You've done everything good... You should consider creating an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), a small running example (one action, one jsp, one field only) to reproduce the example without the need to post your real code, and post it here or, even better, on Struts JIRA :/

Comment: Are `object1.object2.attribute` real property names that you use? If not show the real ones.